Apache Configuration Error in Dockerized PHP Application
I'm trying to Dockerize my PHP application and learn about Docker in the process, but I'm facing a configuration issue with Apache.
Here’s my docker-compose.yml:
services:
  php:
    image: php:8.1.29-fpm-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./admin:/usr/src/admin
    extra_hosts:
      - "docker-admin.localhost:127.0.0.1"
    expose:
      - "9000"
    entrypoint: ["php-fpm"]

  apache-server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./admin:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/admin
    depends_on:
      - php

Here’s my Dockerfile:
FROM httpd:2.4.52-alpine3.15

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/apache2/conf/vhosts

COPY ./conf/* /usr/local/apache2/conf/vhosts
COPY ./httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

And my admin.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName docker-admin.localhost
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/apps/admin/public_html

    <Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/apps/admin/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://php:9000"
    </FilesMatch>

    ErrorLog /usr/local/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Here’s the error I’m getting:
[Sun Oct 06 10:02:48.889047 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 10:tid 131326541519672] [client 192.168.16.1:49194] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/apps/admin/public_html/.htaccess

Here’s my .htaccess file:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

I’ve attached the htaccess file.
directory permissions reference:
-rw-r--r--    1 504      dialout         45 Jun 11  2007 index.html
drwxrwxr-x   12 www-data www-data      4096 Oct  6 09:57 apps


Can anyone help me understand why I am getting this error?
